# How can i represent multiple m:n relations from two tables?

Tags: entity-relationship

My tables:

**medic**->id_medic, name

**patient**->id_patient, name

I have the following situacion:

1. A medic can have many patients and a patient can have many medics
2. A medic can send many messages to a patient and a patient can send many messages to a medic.

how i represent this in the E-R model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have two another tables messages and medic_patient  :

- **medic**->id_medic, name
- **patient**->id_patient, name
- **messages** -> id_message,content, #id_medic_receiver,#id_patient_sender,#id_patient_receiver,#id_medic_sender
- **medic_patient** -> #id_medic,#id_patient

Comment: Please make it clear what you mean by these arrow and hash marks.

Comment: the marke # mean a Foreign key but the arrow mean nothing just a separator between the name of table and the attributes

Comment: Thank you so much **Abdelmjid EL KIHEL**